# How to set the frequency and amplitude values in android device?

Tags: android, audio, frequency, amplitude

I am new to android, and I need to work with the audio of the android device.
I have something like a table of pairs(frequency - amplitude) and I need to set for each frequency the appropriate amplitude, and apply these values to the equalizer of the device, so when a music file is being played, these values will be applied to it.

For example, 
For frequency 1000 Hz, the amplitude should be 0.5.
For frequency 16000 Hz, the amplitude should be 0.8.
etc...

I need to apply these values to the android device equalizer so that each frequency in the music file would have its appropriate amplitude.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What part of it isn't working? Seems like the most straight-forward way would be to create an [Equalizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html); get the number of bands; for each band, get the frequency range and determine which bands are the closest matches to the frequencies in your table; then get the level range for each band and map your amplitudes to those ranges.